# useSelector returns a function instead of array of objects

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

In the `Posts` component, the `posts` variable should receive an array of objects from the useSelector function, rather it is receiving a function, I have consoled a line in each component in the project LINK - [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zypLI.png). `Posts` is rendered first with `posts` variable receiving a function, then the next step - `Form` component is rendered , and then `Posts` is re-rendered this time `posts` variable with an array of objects as it should. I do not understand why is the `Posts` rendered twice and with different outputs.

I want to receive `array of objects` not function at first render,which is used render, each object in the child `Post` component using map function in `Posts`,

> atm I am getting an error `posts.map` is not a function

```
Posts Component

import React from "react";
import Post from "./Post/Post";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "./Posts.css";

const Posts = ({setCurrentId }) => {
  
    const posts =  useSelector((state) => state.posts);

    console.log('This is a Post\'s Component')

    console.log(posts)

 return (
          <div className="outer">
            {
              posts.map((post)=>
              <Post post = {post}/>
              )
            }
          </div>
               
           
         )
}

export default Posts;


Form Component

// import { min } from 'moment';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {createPost, updatePost} from '../../actions/posts'
import FileBase from 'react-file-base64'
// import  image  from '../../assests/box.png';
import './Form.css'


const Form = ({ currentId, setCurrentId }) => {
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
        name: '', description: ' ', csvFile: ''
    });

    const post = useSelector((state)=> currentId ? state.posts.find((p)=>p._id === currentId): null);
    console.log('This is a FORM Component');
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(post){ setPostData(post); }
    }, [post])

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(postData.name === '' || postData.description === ''  )
        {
            clear();
            alert("fields cannot be empty");
        }else{
        if(currentId){
            dispatch(updatePost(currentId, postData));    
        }else{
        dispatch(createPost(postData));
       }
    
        alert("Submitted, thanks");
        clear();
    }
    }  

    const clear = ()=>{
        setCurrentId(null);
        setPostData({name: '', description: ' ', csvFile: ''});
    }  


    return (
    <>
        <form className="ui form  main-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className='form-fields'>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name" value={postData.name}
                    onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, name: e.target.value })} />
            </div>

            <div className='form-fields'>
                <label>Description</label>
                <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" value={postData.description}
                    onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, description: e.target.value })} />
            </div>
             
            <div className='form-fields'>
                {/* <label for="file" class="ui icon button">
                    <i className="file icon"></i>
                    Add File</label>
                <input type="file" id="file" value={postData.csvFile} onDone = {(e) => setPostData({...postData,csvFile: e.target.value})} /> */}
                <FileBase type = 'file' multiple = {false } onDone={({base64})=> setPostData({...postData, csvFile: base64})} />
            </div>

            <button className="ui button submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button className="ui button clear" onClick={()=>clear}>Clear</button>
        </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

please ask if more info needed, TIA

I have two files in the Reducer folder:

`index.js`(Reducer Folder)

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import posts from './posts'

export default combineReducers({ posts })

console.log('This is Index Js file of reducers folder')
```

`posts.js` (Reducer folder)

```
import Posts from "../components/Posts/Posts";

console.log('This is Posts Js file of reducers folder')
export default (posts = [], action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'UPDATE':
             return posts.map((post)=> post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post);
             
        case 'FETCH_ALL':
            return action.payload;
        
        case 'CREATE':
            return [...posts, action.payload];
       

        default:
            return Posts;
    }
```

}

Comment: Show your post reducer

Comment: problem with your reducer

Comment: It looks like maybe your initial state includes `Posts` the component, instead of `posts` the array.

Comment: @AliNauman I have just added the reducer files.

Answer (score 1):

In default case You are returning Posts component in reducer file so change the code as follows, now your issue will be resolved:

```
// import Posts from "../components/Posts/Posts"; // remove it as we dont need it here

console.log('This is Posts Js file of reducers folder')
export default (posts = [], action)=>{
switch(action.type){
    case 'UPDATE':
         return posts.map((post)=> post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post);
         
    case 'FETCH_ALL':
        return action.payload;
    
    case 'CREATE':
        return [...posts, action.payload];
   

    default:
        return posts;
}
}
```

Comment: Bro!!!!, thank you heaps, I've been stuck on this for a while, I can't tell how many times I went over the code, really appreciate you,taking time to look into this and the correct feedback you gave. cheers

Comment: Welcome Brother.